# Excel - VBA - Access chart Axis - Speed issue

Tags: performance, excel, vba, charts

I am running the below code 400 times. I have 60 charts on the sheet. Execution time is 300 sec. If I remove this line

```
 minVal = 0.02 * (cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale - cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale)
```

the speed improves to 190 seconds. This line impacts nothing given minVal is overwritten by 0 right after (for the purpose of the test). I am looking to understand why accessing the axis of the chart is so time consuming and for a workaround.

```
Sub quickAdjustLabels()
Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject
For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    isProdChart = 0
    If cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).ChartType <> 5 Then 'different from pie
      minVal = 0.02 * (cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale - cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale)
      minVal = 0
      For Each myCollection In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
          'if Stack and if not white visible (white visible are the bottom of waterfall charts / white unvisible are the NC stacks) => remove label is too small
          If (myCollection.ChartType = xlColumnStacked Or myCollection.ChartType = xlColumnStacked100) And (myCollection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse Or myCollection.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB <> 16777215) Then
              myCollection.ApplyDataLabels
              vals = myCollection.Values
              For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
                  If Abs(vals(i)) < minVal Then myCollection.Points(i).HasDataLabel = False
              Next
          End If
          If myCollection.Name = Range("Client") Then isProdChart = 1 'Identify productivity charts
      Next myCollection
      'Remove labels on productivity charts
      If isProdChart = 1 Then
          For Each myCollection In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
              If myCollection.ChartType = xlColumnStacked Then myCollection.DataLabels.Delete
          Next
      End If
    End If
Next cht
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you running it 400 times? It's hard to say what the issue might be, without having access to the actual file.  If I run that code in a loop 1000 times against a single chart, only executing the "minVal" lines, it finishes in 0.015 sec, so clearly those lines alone do not seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not the statement that you pointed out, but actually the statements that apply the DataLabels:

```
myCollection.ApplyDataLabels
myCollection.Points(i).HasDataLabel = False
```

Setting the DataLabels take longer time the more points you have in your graph. So trying to avoid running these commands unnecessarily could potentially save you some time. Before setting the values, verify that it is necessary to change them

```
If Not myCollection.HasDataLabels Then
    myCollection.ApplyDataLabels
End If


For i = LBound(Vals) To UBound(Vals)
    shouldHaveLabel = True
    If Abs(Vals(i)) < MinVal Then
        shouldHaveLabel = False
    End If
    If myCollection.Points(i).HasDataLabel <> shouldHaveLabel Then
        myCollection.Points(i).HasDataLabel = shouldHaveLabel
    End If
Next
```

I hope this helps you.

I came to this conclusion by running your code on one of my excel-files with 56 graphs. 
I added a time-measure that would tell me at the end of the execution how long time it took to execute, and ran it over and over again, commenting out different blocks of code until I could pinpoint which block was the one taking long time.

```
Dim tm As Date
tm = Now()    'get timestamp when execution started                            

    ...here goes the code to measure...

Debug.Print(Now()-tm)*24*60*60   'Show how many seconds execution took
```